# How to increase from a single particle multiple in a simulation

Tags: r, ggplot2, simulation, gganimate

Here is what I have so far for the single particle:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magick)
library(gganimate)
library(stringi)
library(ggtext)

particle_mass <- 4.65 #(x 10^-26) 
## A constant that dictates the number of decimal places that the data will be rounded to. Having this set as a constant avoids having to manually adjust a number which appears multiples times throughout the code if you wanted to change the number of decimal places for any reason.
rnd <- 4 
## initial particle coordinates 
x_i <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 0,max = 1), rnd) 
y_i <- round(runif(n = 1, min = 0,max = 1), rnd)

x_velocity <- 400 ## A constant for the x velocity in m/s
y_velocity <- 200 ##A  constant for the y velocity in m/s
time_step <- 0.001 ## A constant for the duration of a single time step in seconds
frame_total <- 200 ## A constant for the number of frames that the animation will be split into (two additional frames are added on at the end)
rate_factor <- 35 ## A factor that controls the playback rate of the animation. Increase this number and the animation will be slowed 

## The x and y displacement components per time step with a factor to slow down the animation to a more easily perceptible speed.
x_jump <- (x_velocity/rate_factor)/frame_total 
y_jump <- (y_velocity/rate_factor)/frame_total 

## Vectors of equal length for x position, y position, and corresponding time steps are initialized.
x_pos <- round(seq(x_i, (x_i + (frame_total*x_jump))-x_jump, x_jump), rnd)
y_pos <- round(seq(y_i, (y_i + (frame_total*y_jump))-y_jump, y_jump), rnd) 
times <- seq(0, (frame_total*time_step)-time_step, time_step)

## A loop that adjusts the direction of the x velocity vector when x = 1 or x = 0 to simulate wall contact
for (i in 2:length(x_pos)) {
  if (x_pos[i-1] > 1 | x_pos[i-1] < 0 ){x_jump = x_jump*(-1)}
  x_pos[[i]] <- round(x_pos[[i-1]] + x_jump, rnd)
}

##  A loop that adjusts the direction of the y velocity vector when y = 1 or y = 0 to simulate wall contact
for (i in 2:length(y_pos)) {
  if (y_pos[i-1] > 1 | y_pos[i-1] < 0 ){y_jump = y_jump*(-1)}
  y_pos[[i]] <- round(y_pos[[i-1]] + y_jump, rnd)
}


bounce <- data.frame(times, x_pos, y_pos) ##time and coordinate position information
bounce$x_dif <- c(0, diff(bounce$x_pos))## change in x position between time steps
bounce$x_turn <- c(0, diff(sign(bounce$x_dif))) ## helps detect changes in direction

## impulse magnitude experienced by the right wall at each time step
bounce <- bounce %>% mutate(impulse_right = case_when((bounce$x_turn) == -2 ~ 2*(x_velocity*particle_mass),
                                                      (bounce$x_turn) != -2 ~ 0))

bounce$cume_impulse_right <- cumsum(bounce$impulse_right) #cumulative impulse on the right wall 
## static plots of the moving particle
bounce_plot <- ggplot(bounce) +
  geom_point(aes(x_pos, y_pos), color = "azure4", size = 1) +
  labs(title = "Single gas particle model") + 
  ylab("") + xlab("") +
  theme_classic() +
  ## axis lines and tick marks
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  ## plot title aesthetics
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Arial", face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, 
                                  size = 9, color = "gray38")) +
  ## The vertical and horizontal lines create a border around the 1 x 1 box that contains the particle
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, color="snow3", size=2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="snow3", size=2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, color="snow3", size=2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=1, color="#CC6666", size=1) 

bounce_anim <- bounce_plot + transition_time(times)

## The desired number of frames and duration of the animation are set within the 'animate' function.
bounce_gif <- animate(bounce_anim, width = 3, height = 3, units = "in", res = 200,
                      nframes = frame_total, renderer = magick_renderer())
```

My plan would be to just create a new data frame for each new particle, and then add a new geom_point line under the ggplot function using that new data. I'm concerned that if I was to add 5, 10 or more particles that the code would end up being very long. Is there a way to add multiple particles to the simulation without having to write so much code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be better from the point of view of avoiding repetition if you bind all your data frames together. Then you probably don't need to alter your plotting code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach based on making a longer dataframe to hold the journey of multiple id's:

```
particle_mass <- 4.65
ids = 5
frames = 200
n = nrow(df)
df <- expand.grid(frame = 1:frames, id = 1:ids)
df$x_pos = runif(n)
df$y_pos = runif(n)
df$x_vel = runif(n, min = -0.1, max = 0.1) 
df$y_vel = runif(n, min = -0.1, max = 0.1) 
df$impulse_right = 0

for(i in 1:ids) {
  for(f in 2:frames) {
    r = f + (i - 1) * frames
    df$x_pos[r] = df$x_pos[r-1] + df$x_vel[r-1]
    df$x_vel[r] = df$x_vel[r-1] * ifelse(df$x_pos[r] < 0 | df$x_pos[r] > 1, -1, 1)
    df$impulse_right[r] = ifelse(df$x_vel[r] < df$x_vel[r-1], 
                                 df$x_vel[r-1] * particle_mass, 0)
    df$y_pos[r] = df$y_pos[r-1] + df$y_vel[r-1]
    df$y_vel[r] = df$y_vel[r-1] * ifelse(df$y_pos[r] < 0 | df$y_pos[r] > 1, -1, 1)
  }
}

ggplot(df, aes(x_pos, y_pos)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = id)) +
  transition_states(frame)
```

[image]